# lodash multi-column sortBy

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

There's a nifty method to sort an array of objects based on several properties:

```
var data = _.sortBy(array_of_objects, ['type', 'name']);
```

However that is only for ascending sorting. Is there some handy way of defining direction per column? E.g.

```
var data = _.sortBy(array_of_objects, [{'type': 'asc'}, {'name': 'desc'}]);
```

Answer (score 413, accepted):

As of **lodash 3.5.0** you can use [sortByOrder](https://lodash.com/docs#sortByOrder) (renamed [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs#orderBy) in v4.3.0):

```
var data = _.sortByOrder(array_of_objects, ['type','name'], [true, false]);
```

Since **version 3.10.0** you can even use standard semantics for ordering (asc, desc):

```
var data = _.sortByOrder(array_of_objects, ['type','name'], ['asc', 'desc']);
```

In **version 4** of lodash this method has been renamed [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs#orderBy):

```
var data = _.orderBy(array_of_objects, ['type','name'], ['asc', 'desc']);
```

Comment: For you info, this function has been renamed to _.orderBy(https://lodash.com/docs#orderBy) in Lodash as of 4.3.0. The normal sort function is called _.sortBy(https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy)

Comment: I'm getting `_.sortByOrder is not a function` in latest version of lodash.

Comment: Assuming you're using lodash 4, `sortByOrder` no longer exists. It is now named `orderBy`

Comment: Why does lodash keep renaming functions?

Comment: The `, ['asc', 'desc']` part is just getting ignored for me with lodash@4.17.10. Everything is just sorted ascending.

Comment: @maninak This is for `_.sortBy`. Try `_.orderBy` instead. Hope this helps.

Comment: var data = _.orderBy(array_of_objects, ['type','name'], ['asc', 'desc']);
 works perfectly for lodash 4.17.10

Comment: would love `'-name'`, `'+type'` etc. support!

Answer (score 59):

You can always use `Array.prototype.reverse()`

```
var data = _.sortBy(array_of_objects, ['type', 'name']).reverse();
```

Comment: ha thats clever. for a numerical sort ascending (lodash defaults descending) I used this:

_.sortBy(array_of_objects, "some_numerical_value_key").reverse()

Comment: While good enough for some cases, the effect of this is to sort descending on BOTH columns, which isn't what the question asks.

Answer (score 16):

**Deep field & multi field & different direction** ordering 
Lodash  >4

```
var sortedArray = _.orderBy(mixedArray,
                            ['foo','foo.bar','bar.foo.bar'],               
                            ['desc','asc','desc']);
```

Comment: Actually this would be the answer now. sortBy does not give you direction, but orderBy does.

Answer (score 15):

It's worth noting that if you want to sort particular properties descending, you don't want to simply append .reverse() at the end, as this will make all of the sorts descending.

To make particular sorts descending, chain your sorts from least significant to most significant, calling .reverse() after each sort that you want to be descending.

```
var data = _(data).chain()
    .sort("date")
    .reverse()    // sort by date descending
    .sort("name") // sort by name ascending
    .result()
```

Since _'s sort is a stable sort, you can safely chain and reverse sorts because if two items have the same value for a property, their order is preserved.

[More information](http://blog.falafel.com/nifty-underscore-tricks-sorting-by-multiple-properties-with-underscore/)

Answer (score 9):

In the documentation of the version 4.11.x, says: `
"This method is like _.sortBy except that it allows specifying the sort orders of the iteratees to sort by. If orders is unspecified, all values are sorted in ascending order. Otherwise, specify an order of "desc" for descending or "asc" for ascending sort order of corresponding values."
(source https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy)

`let sorted = _.orderBy(this.items, ['fieldFoo', 'fieldBar'], ['asc', 'desc'])`

Comment: I think you meant to use `_.sortByOrder`?

Comment: can't find variable _

Answer (score 5):

> Is there some handy way of defining direction per column?

No. You cannot specify the sort order other than by a callback function that inverses the value. Not even this is possible for a multicolumn sort.

You might be able to do

```
 _.each(array_of_objects, function(o) {
     o.typeDesc = -o.type; // assuming a number
 });
 _.sortBy(array_of_objects, ['typeDesc', 'name'])
```

For everything else, you will need to resort to the native `.sort()` with a custom comparison function:

```
 array_of_objects.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a.type - b.type // asc
         || +(b.name>a.name)||-(a.name>b.name) // desc
         || …;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
var data= _.reverse(_.sortBy(res.locals.subscriptionList.items, ['type', 'name']));
```

Comment: This is going to be way slower than just using _.orderBy