# Javascript/jQuery/JSON/localStorage Game, Trouble sorting ranking table numerically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

the below code creates the leaderboard for my completed game, the only thing that I can't get it to do is automatically sort the score high to low. I think I need to put the objects into an array and then sort them, just not sure how.

```
function createLeaderboard() {
        var html;
        html = "<table>";
        html += "<tbody>";
        html += "<th>Username</th>";
        html += "<th>Rank</th>";
        html += "<tr>";

    for(var val in localStorage){


        if (localStorage.getItem(val) !== null && localStorage.getItem(val) !== localStorage.getItem('UsrLoggedIn')){
            var rankData = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(val));

            //console.log(rankData); This will allow you to see the rank data object in your console

            $(rankData).each(function() {                   
                html += "<td>" + rankData.username + "</td>"; 
                html += "<td>" + rankData.rank + "</td> </tr>"; 
            });
        }

    }
    html += "</tbody>";
    html += "</table>";

    $('#rank').append(html);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Lodash is good for this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928841/lodash-multi-column-sortby-descending

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the `rankData` first, `sort` it and finally loop over the sorted array.

```
function createLeaderboard() {
    var html;
    html = "<table>";
    html += "<tbody>";
    html += "<th>Username</th>";
    html += "<th>Rank</th>";
    html += "<tr>";

    var array = [];
    for (var val in localStorage) {
        if (localStorage.getItem(val) !== null && localStorage.getItem(val) !== localStorage.getItem('UsrLoggedIn')) {
            array.push($.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(val)));
        }
    }

    array.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.rank - b.rank;
    });

    array.forEach(function (rankData) {
        html += "<td>" + rankData.username + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + rankData.rank + "</td> </tr>";
    });

    html += "</tbody>";
    html += "</table>";

    $('#rank').append(html);
}
```