# lodash sortByOrder is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, lodash

lodash sortByOrder is not working as expected

Following is a demo code in my angular app.
But sortByOrder is not getting imported correctly.

I;ve updated with latest version of lodash.
I've also updated `@types/lodash`.

```
import { sortByOrder } from 'lodash';
```

```js
const users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 42 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 }
];
 
// sort by `user` in ascending order and by `age` in descending order
_.map(_.sortByOrder(users, ['user', 'age'], ['asc', 'desc']), _.values);
// => [['barney', 36], ['barney', 34], ['fred', 48], ['fred', 42]]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

I am getting following error

```
lodash/ts3.1"' has no exported member 'sortByOrder'.
```

Comment: Lodash has no `sortByOrder` method, only a [`sortBy` one](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy)?

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need lodash for it? Look at this example with vanilla js

```js
const users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 42 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fed', 'age': 40 }
];

let result = users.sort((a,b) => a.user.localeCompare(b.user) || (b.age - a.age));

console.log(result);
```

Since version 4 its called `_.orderBy`

Comment: lodash sortbyOrder offers multiple sortby options & also sort direction. Feels like more easy. What happened to this method(sortByOrder)? . If this is impossible is there a way to sort by multiple params like sortByOrder(from lodash) in vanilla js?

Comment: if you take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928841/lodash-multi-column-sortby-descending its now `orderBy` since version 4

Comment: is there a way to do something like this var data = _.orderBy(array_of_objects, ['item.type','item.name'], ['asc', 'desc']); - instead of keys can I have key paths?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611489/how-to-sort-array-of-objects-with-deep-nested-properties-using-lodash-orderby

Answer (score 2):

Import Lodash like this

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

You can use Lodash `_.orderBy` function to order using multiple properties

```
const data = _.orderBy(users, ['user', 'age'], ['asc', 'desc']);
```