# How to sort array of objects with deep nested properties using lodash orderBy?

Tags: javascript

This is the recommended way of using orderBy from lodash

```
 const data = _.orderBy(array_of_objects, ['type','name'], ['asc', 'desc']); - instead of keys
```

is there a way to do something like this?
instead of object keys `['type','name']` can I pass key paths as string array like this `['type.id','name.entry']`?

So that the expected result would be a sorted array based on deep values.

```
 const data = _.orderBy(array_of_objects, ['type.id','name.entry'], ['asc', 'desc']); - instead of keys
```

I am asking this because we can access an objects deep properties using lodash _.get() like this.

```
_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3
```

So there must be a way of doing this with _.orderBy()

**NB** If there is a way of doing this in vanilla js, please suggest that also.

Currently in my case this is not getting sorted for every keys I pass `['type.id','name.entry']` only either of one is working.

**If this is not possible please suggest how can I sort an array objects with deeply nested props based on multiple deeply nested props(passed as string paths)**

Comment: Doesn't `_.orderBy` also accept callbacks?

Comment: I'm not sure of that. Can you suggest some code?

Comment: Is there any other way of sorting based on multiple fields/keys?

Comment: Or may be combine _.get() and array.sort() ?? if not callback is supported.

Comment: According to the docs, you can just write `_.orderBy(array_of_objects, [x => x.type.id, x => x.name.entry], ['asc', 'desc']);` Maybe even `_.orderBy(array_of_objects, [['type','id'],['name','entry']], ['asc', 'desc']);`, though I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

[orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) does accept a callback, and this can be a list of functions if you need to order based on multiple attributes. This syntax is based on Lodash 4.x.

```
// for ordering based on a single attribute
const orderedData = _.orderBy(arrayOfObject, item => item.id, ['desc']);

// for ordering based on multiple attributes
const orderedData = _.orderBy(arrayOfObject, [
  item => item.id,
  item => item.entry,
], ['desc', 'asc']);
```

Here's an example of how you might sort based on a nested attribute within each object:

```
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    entry: 'a',
    nested: { val: 5 },
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    entry: 'five',
    nested: { val: 1 },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    entry: 'three',
    nested: { val: 2 },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    entry: 'two',
    nested: { val: 3 },
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    entry: 'four',
    nested: { val: 4 },
  },
];


const nestedValueComparator = item => _.get(item, 'nested.val');

const nestedData = _.orderBy(items, nestedValueComparator, ['asc']);
```

Comment: _.sortByAll(users, [
  { 'key': 'user', 'desc': true },
  { 'key': 'age'}, // Default to 'desc': false
  { 'key': 'gender', 'desc': false } // You can also say that explicitly
]);